# Python version issue on Cassandra 3.11.2

Tags: windows, python, cassandra

Searching around I found a lot of thread about this problem (coming from [2012](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4090)) but I can't find an official solution: running `cqlsh.bat`

```
  File "C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\bin\\cqlsh.py", line 146
    except ImportError, e:
```

The error suggests the script is for python 2.
In system environment I have python3, there is a Cassandra version compatible or there is an official fix for this?

Comment: No, `cqlsh` still requires Python2

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you.
I had installed python 2.7 version as mentioned at [Prerequisites](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#prerequisites) and the error no longer appears

Answer (score 0):

Install Python 2.7 and add path to system variable

- For adding path
- got to edit the system environment variable
- then go to environment variables
- in system variables on path click new and
- add your python path

```
C:\Python27\
C:\Python27\Scripts
```